# Most efficient way to create and then look-up key-value pairs

Tags: r, dplyr, foreign-keys

I have a data frame with multiple string inputs. Some of these inputs represent items in the same category, such as `apple` and `banana` both belonging to the group `fruit`.

```
rawdata <- data.frame(food = c("apple","banana","carrot","steak"),
                      drink = c("water","coke","sprite","milk"))

    food  drink
1  apple  water
2 banana   coke
3 carrot sprite
4  steak   milk
```

I would like to first convert these to integers that will serve as foreign keys in a relational table:

```
conv_food <- function(vec) {
  val <- c("apple" = 1L,
           "banana" = 1L,
           "carrot" = 2L,
           "steak" = 3L)
  unname(val[vec])
}

conv_drink <- function(vec) {
  val <- c("water" = 1L,
           "coke" = 2L,
           "sprite" = 2L,
           "milk" = 3L)
  unname(val[vec])
}

cleandata <- rawdata %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    food = conv_food(food),
    drink = conv_drink(drink)
  )

  food drink
1    1     1
2    1     2
3    2     2
4    3     3
```

Next, I construct my relational data frames:

```
switchback_food <- data.frame(key = c(1,2,3),
                              val = c("fruit","vegetable","meat"))

switchback_drink <- data.frame(key = c(1,2,3),
                              val = c("water","soda","dairy"))
```

And perform a left join and clean up the variable names and select only what I want:

```
cleandata %>% 
  dplyr::left_join(switchback_food, by = c("food" = "key")) %>% 
  dplyr::left_join(switchback_drink, by = c("drink" = "key")) %>% 
  dplyr::select(food = val.x, drink = val.y)

       food drink
1     fruit water
2     fruit  soda
3 vegetable  soda
4      meat dairy
```

This works well, but there are multiple problems:

1. It is unwieldy to write. I have to write these individual functions for each column of `rawdata` because in my actual dataset, there are multiple different entries that are (for my purposes) actually the same thing but are not entered the same. In my example, this is why I changed both `apple` and `banana` to `fruit`. Is there any easier way to assign the possible data entries to their respective integers?
2. I have to have multiple data frames, one for each relational table. Is there an easier way to store this data, perhaps in a single data frame with a column of lists? I tried this but couldn't figure out how to retrieve the proper entry given a column name from `rawdata` and an integer `key`.
3. After I `left_join` the data, I'm left with duplicate columns. And in order to `select`, I have to specify `food = val.x` and `drink = val.y`. This could become very cumbersome when I am joining 50-60 columns. It would nice if when I did `left_join(switch_backfood, by c("food" = "key"))`, the original `food` column was simply replaced with their corresponding strings from the `switchback_food` table.

Are there any recommendations for streamlining this process of converting strings to integers then back to different strings based on data stored in a relational table?

I don't want to use factors because in reality, the values in my data frame are not `apple` and `banana` but are rather quite long and descriptive, such as `laparoscopic approach with open assist and unplanned conversion to open`. These would be very unwieldy in manipulating my data and it is far easier to refer to integer keys. Additionally, I'd like the option for the user to simply change the relational table if he/she wants to change the way the data is presented without having to mess with the actual data.

Comment: `factors` are not working for you?

Comment: I don’t want to use factors.

Comment: Take a look at package `dm` (https://krlmlr.github.io/dm/index.html)